# 20.04 Google Chrome opens but freezes when I enter full screen in YouTube, or when I resize it and then maximize it

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

Basically, in the case of smaller window (for example when I have a split screen), when I try maximizing it, window looks like it is full size, but if I want to open YouTube using bookmark it doesn't work, it doesn't response no caret in top bar, no highlighting bookmark buttons... However if i click on where YouTube bookmark used to be, that opens YouTube. So it's like the window stays small, but shows me full screen. Also it's not the screen that freezes because I can close chrome window, minimize it.. so it's the window that freezes.

The thing is, I have i3wm installed, and when I'm trying to do the same thing using i3wm everything works. Could this be the problem? Is anyone else having similar issue? I just want to figure out is Chrome, Ubuntu, i3 or something else the problem.

I appreciate any help guys, I don't want to go back to Windows or to use Mozilla.

Comment: When in doubt, the first step with Chrome on Linux is to disable hardware acceleration and then restart the browser to see if the behavior exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to latest versions of the chrome, can you try disabling Hw acceleration,  it must be in settings->advance->system